# There are no permissions to edit files on the local machine that are created in the docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

There is a workspace container (laradock - special under laravel), I go inside under the root with the docker-compose exec -w / var / www workspace bash command and use a special command  "php artisan make: model TestModel" to create a file.

It is naturally created here with the following rights -rw-r - r-- root root. And naturally in PhpSrorm I have no rights to edit it.

What can I do to have the right to edit the files that I create inside the container on my lacal machine? I can make chmod 777 on this file, and then there will be rights, but it needs to be done every time after every file creation. In laradock in the .env file in the settings I have WORKSPACE_PUID = 1000 and WORKSPACE_PGID = 1000. My user on the local host has uid = 1000 (andrey) gid = 1000 (andrey) groups = 1000 (andrey).

Why it does not work, and on the local machine I do not have rights to the files that I create using php artisan make: .....

Comment: Please format your question to not appear like a wall of text. It will help get an answer faster

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're trying to run this command from inside a container, instead of running it directly on your host (as the user owning the directory, without the Docker intermediary)?

Comment: Because the "php artisan..." command can only run inside the container, because the php interpreter is installed inside container